# How can I get a list of all my unscheduled reminders?

Tags: reminders

My basic workflow is to add tasks I need to do to my "Todo" list in Reminders. Then, every morning, I scan the list and schedule some for today, and they show up in the "Today" list. Then, I just work from that list, add any new reminders to the Todo list, and, if there's a follow-up for a task, I just reschedule it for a later date.

However, it's annoying to scan my whole list of tasks to figure out what I want to do today because many of those tasks are already scheduled for a later date, so there's no point in triaging them today. So, I'm wondering, how can I get a list of all my unscheduled tasks in Reminders, so that I can just look at that list in the morning?